# How to determine an execution device for opencv transparent API

Tags: opencv, opencl

I have  a code I wrote using `Umat` in opencv 3.1

I have several devices on my system, an Nvidia GPU Tesla k20 and Intel graphics HD 4600, I'd like to run my Umat OpenCL code on the Intel graphics HD, and on different thread run my CUDA code on Nvidia device.

How can I determine Umat execution platform?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desired device via OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE environment variable here you have some examples:

```
OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE = NVIDIA:GPU
Variable Name: OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE
OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE = AMD:GPU
OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE = AMD:Pitcairn
```

(If you have few AMD devices.Pitcairn is the device name.)